# Adding a name to a string with PowerShell

Tags: file, powershell, scripting, rename

I have a host of files in a folder that are named as a string. I've found some information similar to what I'm trying to do [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/11/22/use-powershell-to-rename-files-in-bulk.aspx). I am not replacing existing characters in the string. I would just like to add *Quote_* to the beginning of each file name. I have about 1500-2000 files that need altering.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is (for current directory):

```
Get-Childitem | % { Rename-Item $_ "Quote_$_"}
```

It will add `Quote_` to the beginning of every filename in directory you're using cmdlet in.

To ommit files that already have `Query_` in their names, we can use simple clause to ommit them before replace:

```
Get-ChildItem | Where-Object { $_ -NotMatch "Quote_" } | % { Rename-Item $_ "Quote_$_"}
```

Comment: Some of the files already have the *Quote_* character in the name. If I use a for loop, will that work?

Comment: You may add a simple Where clause that it should ommit filename that are like `Quote_*`

Comment: I've added additional code so that it ommits filenames containing `Quote_`. Also, if my answer resolves your problem, please consider marking it as such.